# How to Implement Dependent Dropdownlist in MVC4 Razor and using SQL server also

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I've 2 `Dropdownlist` called States and Country. but only the States `DDL(DropdownList)` will be enable the country `DDL` will be diable. when I select a option in States which is already stored in `SQL`. The Country `DDL` Should Show the Selected state's Country automatically from `DB`. Please help Me.....

Ex:If i select state as "Delhi" then the Country `DDL` automatically should display as`"INDIA"`

Comment: You should use ajax on first `Select` changing to fetch data for second DropDown

Comment: Don't use DDL for dropdownlist, DDL is widely used to mean Data Definition Language in SQL

Comment: i hope your requirement does not make sence. this is not the right way. you can do it in opposite way i mean select country then state dropdownlist will show all states in the particular country.If you are proceed in this way what will do if same statename came in different country ?? i don't know practically is there any state name is like that . but anyway your way is wrong

Comment: if you are already save the related state and country details in database then you can easily get that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note : As per your requirement you need to show country name when user selects the state then why you need dropdownlist for country ?? it is better to use a label for that.

For you requirement first you have to maintain a table which stores country and it's state like below  then it will be easy to take values,if your scenario is more complicated then you can use foreign key relations too

```
id state        country 

1   delhi        india

2   kerala       india

3   California    usa
```

then you can easily select the country based on state

```
select distinct country from tablename where 
    state ='yourstate'
```

Then your JS

the below codewill be in onchange event of your state dropdown

then just take value from state dropdown and assign to a variable and pass it via ajax

```
 var StateName= $("#statedropdownlistid").val();// jquery solution need js then change the code 

 $.ajax({
            type: "Get",
            url:"/ControllerName/FunctionName",,
            data: JSON.stringify({ StateName: StateName }),
            success: function (data) {
              document.getElementById("labelid").innerHTML =data;
            },
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: 'application/json',
            traditional: true
        });
```

Then in mVC Controller

```
public JsonResult FunctionName(string StateName)
        {

            try
            {
               //code for getting your value from database, you can write a simple stored procedure in database and get the values here 
                return Json(new { data= assignthevaluefromdatabase }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                return Json(new { data= "Error" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

For your requirement, Have two tables *States* & *Countries*. One to many relationship. Foreign key of *CountryId* in States table. Have an ajax function called (by jQuery or javascript) when states drop down list's selectedItemChange event fires.